# Page speed is monitoring the wrong url

Tags: url, redirect, click, multilingual

this is my german magazine. the start page is:

https://www.theclubmap.com/

Page speed is switching automatically to:

https://www.theclubmap.com/en/home-english/

Why does this happen?

BG Jens